# var json = [:] null dictionary

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I want to create null json object in swift 3 xcode 9 and use everywhere.

For example:

```
var json = [:] // -> Error = Empty collection literal requires an explicit type
               // So this is not correct, but how can I create this then?

var jsonResult: NSDictionary {
    get {
        return self.json as NSDictionary
    }
    set(newJson) {
        self.json = newJson as! [AnyHashable : Any]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is Swift *cannot* **infer** type from the *empty* dictionary. The type of the key and value can be `String`, `Int`, `Float` or anything for that matter. So what you need to do is specify the type during declaration.

```
var json: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:] // Change AnyHashable to the type you are going to use for the key so that you don't have to cast it everytime.
```

But if you had a default entry in the dictionary, it wouldn't have complained.

```
var json = ["One": 1]
```

It would have inferred the type of the dictionary as `[String: Int]`.

**Note:** You will you only be able to use this dictionary with `String` keys and `Int` values after that.

Comment: Why declare as `AnyHashable`? json has `String` keys.

Comment: @AshleyMills, yes you are right. I am just keeping the answer generic. Maybe he needs the change the string keys from json to some other hashable? (Most of the time they don't, but like i said. Just keeping it generic).

Comment: The question explicitly asks about creating a _"null json object"_, so your answer has an error.

Comment: @AshleyMills because key needs to be hashable? and `Any` is not hashable? I'm not changing my answer because i do not believe it's wrong. I'll take the downvotes :) Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: @AshleyMills why did you edit your comment where you asked "Why did you not keep the key as `Any` if you wanted it to be generic"?

Comment: JSON dictionary keys are always strings

Comment: @LeoDabus they might be in the response, but the person can choose to store it any way he likes?

Comment: What do you mean? This is pointless. You should suggest a totally different approach using Codable protocol

Comment: You are not helping fixing his code and keeping him in the wrong direction

Comment: @LeoDabus when i saw the question, i thought he would have written his code thinking type inference would take care of it. So i approached the answer from that point and explained in a generic way than directly for the answer, so that if he uses a dictionary elsewhere it might help him there.

Comment: Thanks for response

Answer (score 2):

`var json = [:]` doesn't tell the compiler what the key or value type of your dictionary are. The message is pretty clear

> Empty collection literal **requires an explicit type**

You need to say

```
var json: [String: Any] = [:]
```

Also, don't use `NSDictionary`s in Swift

Comment: _"this is not work"_ - Won't compile? Crashes? Unexpected data?

Comment: when i call jsonResult, the variable not convert other type. For exampla
   var companyCategories = [Category]()
                    if let categories = jsonResult["categories"] as? NSArray {
                        for category in categories {
                            var categoryId = ""
                            if let ctgryId = category["id"] as? String { **-> ERROR = Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator. Element '(aka 'Any') has no subsccript members**
                                categoryId = ctgryId 
         
                    }

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this information & code

Comment: @YusufElosman You can avoid these ***Any has no subsccript members*** errors if you use Swift native collection types. Both `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` don't provide type information and the compiler **must** know the static types of all subscripted objects. Dealing with JSON replace `NSArray` with `[[String:Any]]` and `NSDictionary` with `[String:Any]` this solves those issues.